# Apple app site association - bad JSON content

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate

The Apple-app-site association is failing. Haven't found a solution yet. I checked for valid JSON in the JSON validator which says -valid JSON
But it doesn't redirect to the app. I have hosted
The apple-app-site association file (without the extension as mentioned in the Apple documentation) has no restrictions on the web server and that URL. I have validated the link on this web page [https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator]

[image]

But it didn't redirect the app.
I found this method to validate AASA files

```
curl -v https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/yourdomain.com
```

The response is like this

```
Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Wed, 04 Jan 2023 17:52:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 10
Connection: keep-alive
Apple-Failure-Details: {"cause":"invalid character '/' looking for beginning of value"}
Apple-Failure-Reason: SWCERR00401 Bad JSON content
```

Please someone help me to understand what is wrong with this JSON

```
    {
  "applinks": {
    "details": [
      {
        "appIDs": [
          "teamID.com.app.menu" //example 
        ],
        "components": [
          {
            "/": "/*",
            "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /"
          },
          {
            "/": "/contact-us/*",
            "exclude": true,
            "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /contact-us/ and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "appclips": {
    "apps": [
      
    ]
  }
}
```

Links redirected when I added this mode on the simulator
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Remove *//example* from your JSON.